# What does * address(found in printf) mean in assembly?

Tags: c, disassembly

Disassembling `printf` doesn't give much info:

```
(gdb) disas printf
Dump of assembler code for function printf:
0x00401b38 <printf+0>:  jmp    *0x405130
0x00401b3e <printf+6>:  nop
0x00401b3f <printf+7>:  nop
End of assembler dump.


(gdb) disas 0x405130
Dump of assembler code for function _imp__printf:
0x00405130 <_imp__printf+0>:    je     0x405184 <_imp__vfprintf+76>
0x00405132 <_imp__printf+2>:    add    %al,(%eax)
```

How is it implemented under the hood?

Why disassembling doesn't help?

What does `*` mean before `0x405130`?

Comment: Why don't you start with `puts` rather than `printf`?

Comment: `jmp *addr` is a computed call: take the value at address `addr` and jump there. But why not try to read some source code instead of reverse-engineering the binary?

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq ,I've pasted the value at address `addr` above,but it still doesn't make sense why `*` is necessary..

Comment: jmp 0x405130, would jump to the location 0x405130 -- whereas

jmp *0x405130, will look for an address value at the address 0x405130, then jump to that value

Comment: But `disas 0x405130` shows it is a instruction at `0x405130`,no an address

Comment: Don't use disas 0x405130.  Display the 32-bit value stored at 0x405130.  That is the new value for EPC register.

Comment: @Heath Hunnicutt,how to do it with gdb?

Comment: @Mask - I believe either x/w 0x405130 or x/4b 0x405130 will work as synonyms to perform that function.

Comment: @Mask - just curious, what toolset are you using (version, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for

> What does * mean before 0x405130?

I'm not familiar with gdb's disassembler, but it looks like the `jmp *0x405130` is an indirect jump through a pointer.  Instead of disassembling what's at 0x405130 you should dump the 4 bytes of memory there.  I'd be willing to bet that you'll find another address there, and if you disassemble *that* location you'll find `printf()`'s code (how readable that disassembly might be is another story).

In other words, `_imp__printf` is a pointer to `printf()`, not `printf()` itself.

---

Edit from after more information in the comments below:

A litle poking around indicates that `jmp *0x405130` is the GAS/AT&T assembly syntax for `jmp [0x405130]` instruction when using the Intel assembly syntax.

What makes this curious is that you say that the gdb command `x/xw 0x405130` shows that that address contains `0x00005274` (which seems to match up with what you got when you disassembled 0x405130).  However, that would mean that `jmp [0x405130]` would try to jump to address `0x00005274`, which doesn't seem right (and gdb said as much when you tried to disassemble that address.

It's possible that the `_imp_printf` entry is using some sort of lazy binding technique where the first time execution jumps through 0x405130, it hits the 0x00005274 address which causes the OS to field a trap and fixup the dynamic link.  After the fixup, the OS will restart execution with the correct link address in 0x405130.  But this is sheer guesswork on my part.  I have no idea if the system you're using does anything like this (indeed, I don't even know what system you're running on), but it's technically possible.  If something like this is going on, you won't see the correct address in 0x405130 until after the first call to `printf()` has been made.

I think you'll need to single step through a call to `printf()` at the assembly level to see what's really going on.

---

Updated information with a GDB session:

Here's the problem you're running into - you're looking at the process before the system has loaded DLLs and fixed up the linkages to the DLLs.  Here's a debugging session of a simple "hello world" program compiled with MinGW debugged with GDB:

```
C:\temp>\mingw\bin\gdb test.exe
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.1
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "mingw32".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from C:\temp/test.exe...done.

(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x004012f0 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x004012f1 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x004012f3 <+3>:     sub    $0x8,%esp
   0x004012f6 <+6>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x004012f9 <+9>:     mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x004012fe <+14>:    add    $0xf,%eax
   0x00401301 <+17>:    add    $0xf,%eax
   0x00401304 <+20>:    shr    $0x4,%eax
   0x00401307 <+23>:    shl    $0x4,%eax
   0x0040130a <+26>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x0040130d <+29>:    mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
   0x00401310 <+32>:    call   0x401850 <_alloca>
   0x00401315 <+37>:    call   0x4013d0 <__main>
   0x0040131a <+42>:    movl   $0x403000,(%esp)
   0x00401321 <+49>:    call   0x4018b0 <printf>
   0x00401326 <+54>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0040132b <+59>:    leave
   0x0040132c <+60>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
```

Note that disassembling `printf()` leads to a similar indirect jump:

```
(gdb) disas printf
Dump of assembler code for function printf:
   0x004018b0 <+0>:     jmp    *0x4050f8     ; <<-- indirect jump
   0x004018b6 <+6>:     nop
   0x004018b7 <+7>:     nop
End of assembler dump.
```

And that the `_imp__printf` symbiol makes no sense as code...

```
(gdb) disas 0x4050f8
Dump of assembler code for function _imp__printf:
   0x004050f8 <+0>:     clc                 ; <<-- how can this be printf()?
   0x004050f9 <+1>:     push   %ecx
   0x004050fa <+2>:     add    %al,(%eax)
End of assembler dump.
```

or as a pointer...

```
(gdb) x/xw 0x4050f8
0x4050f8 <_imp__printf>:        0x000051f8  ; <<-- 0x000051f8 is an invalid pointer
```

Now, let's set a breakpoint at `main()`, and run to it:

```
(gdb) break main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40131a: file c:/temp/test.c, line 5.

(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\temp/test.exe
[New Thread 11204.0x2bc8]
Error while mapping shared library sections:
C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\ntdll32.dll: No such file or directory.

Breakpoint 1, main () at c:/temp/test.c:5
5           printf( "hello world\n");
```

`printf()` looks the same:

```
(gdb) disas printf
Dump of assembler code for function printf:
   0x004018b0 <+0>:     jmp    *0x4050f8
   0x004018b6 <+6>:     nop
   0x004018b7 <+7>:     nop
End of assembler dump.
```

but `_imp__printf` looks different - the dynamic link has now been fixed up:

```
(gdb) x/xw 0x4050f8
0x4050f8 <_imp__printf>:        0x77bd27c2
```

And if we disassemble what `_imp__printf` is now pointing to, it might not be very readable, but clearly it's code now.  This is `printf()` as implemented in MSVCRT.DLL:

```
(gdb) disas _imp__printf
Dump of assembler code for function printf:
   0x77bd27c2 <+0>:     push   $0x10
   0x77bd27c4 <+2>:     push   $0x77ba4770
   0x77bd27c9 <+7>:     call   0x77bc84c4 <strerror+554>
   0x77bd27ce <+12>:    mov    $0x77bf1cc8,%esi
   0x77bd27d3 <+17>:    push   %esi
   0x77bd27d4 <+18>:    push   $0x1
   0x77bd27d6 <+20>:    call   0x77bcca49 <msvcrt!_lock+4816>
   0x77bd27db <+25>:    pop    %ecx
   0x77bd27dc <+26>:    pop    %ecx
   0x77bd27dd <+27>:    andl   $0x0,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x77bd27e1 <+31>:    push   %esi
   0x77bd27e2 <+32>:    call   0x77bd400d <wscanf+3544>
   0x77bd27e7 <+37>:    mov    %eax,-0x1c(%ebp)
   0x77bd27ea <+40>:    lea    0xc(%ebp),%eax
   0x77bd27ed <+43>:    push   %eax
   0x77bd27ee <+44>:    pushl  0x8(%ebp)
   0x77bd27f1 <+47>:    push   %esi
   0x77bd27f2 <+48>:    call   0x77bd3330 <wscanf+251>
   0x77bd27f7 <+53>:    mov    %eax,-0x20(%ebp)
   0x77bd27fa <+56>:    push   %esi
   0x77bd27fb <+57>:    pushl  -0x1c(%ebp)
   0x77bd27fe <+60>:    call   0x77bd4099 <wscanf+3684>
   0x77bd2803 <+65>:    add    $0x18,%esp
   0x77bd2806 <+68>:    orl    $0xffffffff,-0x4(%ebp)
   0x77bd280a <+72>:    call   0x77bd281d <printf+91>
   0x77bd280f <+77>:    mov    -0x20(%ebp),%eax
   0x77bd2812 <+80>:    call   0x77bc84ff <strerror+613>
   0x77bd2817 <+85>:    ret
   0x77bd2818 <+86>:    mov    $0x77bf1cc8,%esi
   0x77bd281d <+91>:    push   %esi
   0x77bd281e <+92>:    push   $0x1
   0x77bd2820 <+94>:    call   0x77bccab0 <msvcrt!_lock+4919>
   0x77bd2825 <+99>:    pop    %ecx
   0x77bd2826 <+100>:   pop    %ecx
   0x77bd2827 <+101>:   ret
   0x77bd2828 <+102>:   int3
   0x77bd2829 <+103>:   int3
   0x77bd282a <+104>:   int3
   0x77bd282b <+105>:   int3
   0x77bd282c <+106>:   int3
End of assembler dump.
```

It's probably harder to read than you might hope because I'm not sure if proper symbols are available for it (or whether GDB can properly read those symbols).

However, [as I mentioned in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559849/what-does-addressfound-in-printf-mean-in-assembly/2562364#2562364), you can get typically get the source for C runtime routines with your compiler, whether open source or not. MinGW doesn't come with the source for MSVDRT.DLL since that's a Windows thing, but you can get the source for it (or something pretty close to it) in a Visual Studio distribution - I think that even the free [VC++ Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2008-Visual-CPP) comes with runtime source (but I might be wrong about that).

Comment: How to do what you said with gdb? -- "Instead of disassembling what's at 0x405130 you should dump the 4 bytes of memory there"

Comment: @Mask: I have little experience with GDB (especially at the command line), but I think that something like "`x/xw 0x405130`" will display the contents of that memory location. In a Windows debugger, I'd type "`dd 0x405130`" if that's any help.

Comment: I tried,only get weird things:`(gdb) x/xw 0x405130
0x405130 <_imp__printf>:        0x00005274
(gdb) disas 0x00005274
No function contains specified address.
(gdb) x 0x00005274
0x5274: Cannot access memory at address 0x5274`

Comment: @Mask: sorry - looks like my guess might be wrong.  However, you should be able to see exactly what's going on my single stepping in GCC at the assembly level- that may be a better approach to find the 'meat' of the `printf()` function.

Comment: If that instruction is to fetch the value in the address([addr]),why disas addr make sense?

Comment: @mask: the disassembly doesn't make much sense - the 1st instruction (bytes 0x74 0x52), `je 0x405184 <_imp__vfprintf+76>`, will conditionally jump based on a flag that hasn't been set one way or another, and the 2nd (bytes 0x00 0x00), `add %al,(%eax)`, is the instruction for the opcode consisting of zero bytes, which is nearly always an indication that garbage is being disassembled (and what is `EAX` pointing to anyway? It hasn't been setup to anything).

Comment: If it's invalid,what's `_imp__printf+0`,`_imp__printf+2` there for?

Comment: @Mask: the memory location `0x405130` has the symbolic name `_imp__printf`.  I believe this is supposed to be a pointer to the actual location of the `printf()` function rather than the location of the function itself. However, there's enough the I don't understand that I'm not sure. What tools & platform are you using?

Comment: I'm in windows,using MinGW and msys.BTW,where does the symbolic name come from?Symbol table by `-g` option?

Comment: @Mask: yes the symbol table comes from the `-g` option.  I've updated the answer with a lot more detail since I've been able to recreate your scenario.

Comment: What's the the complete expanded form of commands like `x/wx`,`x/bx`?I know `w`/`b` means `word`/`byte`,what about `x`?

Comment: @Mask: Unfortunately you're asking the wrong guy for details about GDB - what you see in my answer above is about the extent of my expertise... but to answer your specific question about the `x` command:  the command means 'eXamine memory', the `x` in the display format option (after the `/`) means 'heXadecimal'.  More details here: http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html

Answer (score 8):

Here's one particular implementation, http://ftp.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/src/lib/libc/stdio/printf.c and  http://ftp.fr.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/src/lib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c

Comment: And here's how glibc does it: http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/vfprintf.c;h=6e0e85cd7cca9f4dfc9e86fb702db131ab2e1639;hb=refs/heads/master#l195

Answer (score 3):

The `*` is AT&T assembler syntax for indirect memory reference. I.e.

```
jmp *<addr>
```

means "jump to the address stored in `<addr>`".

It is equivalent to the following Intel syntax:

```
jmp [addr]
```

> Branch addressing using registers or memory operands must be prefixed by a '*'

[Source](http://sig9.com/articles/att-syntax)

Comment: If that instruction is to fetch the value in the address(`[addr]`),why `disas addr` make sense?

Comment: What makes you think it makes sense?

Comment: The output of `disas addr` is valid(in my post).

Comment: It doesn't look valid to me. Have you tried disas'ing the address it points to?

Comment: If it's invalid,what's `_imp__printf+0`,`_imp__printf+2` there for?

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all C compilers provide the source the their runtime libraries - not just open source compilers. Unfortunately, they're often written in rather difficult to follow form and they don't generally come with design rationale documents.

So, a very nice resource for dealing with that problem is [P.J. Plauger's "The Standard C Library"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131315099), which provides not only the source for a library implementation but also has details on how it's designed and the special situations that such a library might have to consider.

At the prices that some of the 'used' versions of the book are being offered, it's a steal and should be on any serious C programmer's bookshelf.

Plauger has similar books targeting the C++ library that I think have similar value:

- [The Draft Standard C++ Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131170031)
- [The C++ Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134376331)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say disassembling works just fine here, and that printf is implemented 'under the hood' here using vfprintf, which is pretty much what you'd expect.  Note that assembler is typically much more verbose than the C, and time consuming to make sense of where you don't have the annotated source.  Compiler output is not a great way of teaching yourself assembler either.

Answer (score 0):

`printf()` is most likely located in a dynamic shared library.
The dynamic linker fills a table with the addresses of the imported functions; that's why you have to make that indirect call.

I don't really recall how this works; it's probable that optimizations complicate the process.
But you get the idea.